# how to use topMargin in ColumnLayout in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to use topMargin in ColumnLayout. but i am facing some issues.
Could some one help me out of this.

**Here is my code**

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle{
        anchors.fill: parent
        ColumnLayout{
            id: columlayout
            Rectangle{
                width: 100
                height: 100
                color: "red"
            }
            Rectangle{
                Layout.topMargin: 50
                width: 100
                height: 100
                color: "green"
            }
            Rectangle{
                width: 100
                height: 100
                color: "blue"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Issue:**

Cannot assign to non-existent property "topMargin"

Answer (score 2):

The [margin properties](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#margins-attached-prop) were introduced in `QtQuick.Layouts 1.2`, so you must import that version, not `1.1`.